Generate a MaterialColor from a regular color without using members deprecated in Flutter 3.27.0
In Flutter 3.27.0, this function is showing that these members are deprecated: .red, .green, .blue, .value.
// Generate a MaterialColor from a regular color
MaterialColor materialColor(Color thisColor) {
  final int red = thisColor.red;
  final int green = thisColor.green;
  final int blue = thisColor.blue;
  final Map<int, Color> shades = {
    50: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .1),
    100: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .2),
    200: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .3),
    300: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .4),
    400: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .5),
    500: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .6),
    600: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .7),
    700: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .8),
    800: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, .9),
    900: Color.fromRGBO(red, green, blue, 1),
  };
  return MaterialColor(thisColor.value, shades);
}

Can anyone provide an equivalent function without using the now-deprecated members? Thanks in advance.

It looks like some people is complaining about Color.value being deprecated, you can follow up on this here in this GitHub issue
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/160184
But in the meantime and as you requested, an equivalent to your code should be something like this
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

MaterialColor materialColor(Color thisColor) {
  final double r = thisColor.r;
  final double g = thisColor.g;
  final double b = thisColor.b;
  final Map<int, Color> shades = {
    50: Color.from(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: .1),
    100: Color.from(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: .2),
    200: Color.from(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: .3),
    300: Color.from(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: .4),
    400: Color.from(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: .5),
    500: Color.from(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: .6),
    600: Color.from(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: .7),
    700: Color.from(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: .8),
    800: Color.from(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: .9),
    900: Color.from(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1),
  };
  return MaterialColor(thisColor.toInt32, shades);
}

extension ColorEx on Color {
  static int floatToInt8(double x) {
    return (x * 255.0).round() & 0xff;
  }

  int get toInt32 {
    return floatToInt8(a) << 24 | floatToInt8(r) << 16 | floatToInt8(g) << 8 | floatToInt8(b) << 0;
  }
}

I took the extension method from that GitHub issue, in order to convert the Color to the right value as int
